# Better code: Extend LINQ class, or create separate helper class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out what the better/cleaner/more maintainable way is, for the following problem. My "Customer" class is generated via LINQ from the database. The customer has a special activation link which is a URL that needs to be generated from data from both a Customer instance and some static configuration data.

Solution 1: Extend the partial Customer Class with `GenerateActivationUrl()` method which will fetch data from its own instance and call the static class which has configuration data and then render the URL and return it as a string.

Solution 2: Make a "LinkBuilder" static helper class which takes a Customer as an argument for a `GenerateActivationUrl` (Customer customer) method which will then take the needed data from the customer instance and also the static configuration data and then return the URL as a string.

Which solution is better, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "extend"? inheritance? extension methods?

Personally, I'd use a partial class (in the same namespace, but a different file to the codegen) to expose this as a property:

```
namespace MyDalNamespace {
    partial class Customer {
        public string ActivationUrl {get {/* some code */ }}
    }
}
```

This directly binds `ActivationUrl` as a regular property on the `Customer` instance.

As a property, it can participate in data-binding (unlike extension methods, which can't).

If you *had* to do "option 2" (perhaps you don't have access to the DAL dll), then an extension method would be appropriate:

```
GenerateActivationUrl(this Customer customer) { ... } // note "this"
```

Comment: Yes I meant partial class "extension". Not extension methods. Simply adding to the LINQ generated partial class.

Comment: Your comment still isn't 100% clear; but don't edit the generated output, if that is what you mean.